# dc.js charts not working in django

Tags: javascript, django, dc.js

I have a Django URL which generates the JSON data for the charts which works (see `url(r'^report/get_issues_json/$', get_issues_json, name='get_issues_json'),` in issues/urls.py) but when I call that URL from my javascript file (static/js/graph.js) it doesn't render anything (no errors or anything in the console) in my html page (issues/templates/report.html)
the code is in this github branch here:  https://github.com/jordandaly/issue_tracker/tree/dashboard

Comment: Any errors in the browser console? Also, check the `error` parameter in `makeGraphs`.

Comment: @Gordon no errors in the browser console or from the `error` parameter in `makeGraphs` unfortunately

Comment: Hrrrm, looks like you've hit the great "nothing happens". I guess, check that your code really is running at all? Time for developer tools. Check that the received data has the shape that you expect? Check that each each group's `.all()` returns some key/value pairs with the values you expect? Etc etc blah blah woof woof.